# How to intercept angular when user visit `isr/uuidv4` it add query `isr/uuidv4?timeZone=Asia/Jakarta` before sending it to the server?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

My goal is to add `timeZone` query when user visit `isr/uuidv4` path. So the final path should be `isr/uuidv4?timeZone=Asia/Jakarta`.

What I've tried: Use `CanMatchFn`. However, it does not intercept. It gets executed twice in server and also client.

So calling `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` will return `undefined` in server and `Asia/Jakarta` in browser.

This is what I expect

1. user visit `isr/uuidv4`
2. user gets redirected to `isr/uuidv4?timeZone=Asia/Jakarta`.
3. server render `isr/uuidv4?timeZone=Asia/Jakarta`.

But this is what actually happen

1. user visit `isr/uuidv4`
2. server do not render anything because the guard return false.
3. user get empty html and redirect to `isr/uuid?timeZone=Asia/Jakarta`.
4. user render the page.

```
import { isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';
import { PLATFORM_ID, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CanMatchFn, Router } from '@angular/router';

export const uUIDv4TimeZoneGuard: CanMatchFn = (route, segments) => {
  let router = inject(Router);
  
  let queryParamMap = router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extractedUrl.queryParamMap;

  if (queryParamMap?.get('timeZone') === null) {
    let platformID = inject(PLATFORM_ID)
    let isServer = isPlatformServer(platformID);

    if (isServer) { return false; }

    router.navigate(
      ['isr/uuidv4'],
      {
        queryParams: {
          timeZone: Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
        }
      }
    )
  }

  return true;
};
```

Comment: Just create an interceptor for it: https://angular.io/guide/http-intercept-requests-and-responses

Comment: @nll_ptr would you care to provide an example? I am unable to trigger HTTP Intercept when user visit the path /isr/uuidv4